# Prevent SSH Access to EC2-instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am setting up EC-2 RHEL instance for my users to allow file transfer using filezilla or WinScp.I have made accounts for them.Not any of them is added in sudoers. How can I prevent ssh access to any of the user and allow only zip,tar files to be uploaded?

Comment: You can use security groups and only allow ssh from your IP. There's no doubt a way to prevent individuals users ssh'ing in, but I don't know it - someone else will help though.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of the users you want to deny ssh access for in the same group and then use

```
DenyGroups <group>
```

directive in your sshd_config file.

```
DenyGroups
             This keyword can be followed by a list of group name patterns, 
             separated by spaces.  Login is disallowed for users whose primary 
             group or supplementary group list matches one of the patterns.  
             Only group names are valid; a numerical group ID is not recognized.  
             By default, login is allowed for all groups.  The allow/deny direc‐
             tives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, 
             DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.  All of the specified user and 
             group tests must succeed, before user is allowed to log in.
```